# Include library with require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I've added an external library `spin.js` to my project,built by `require.js and backbone`.
I've added path in `main.js`:

```
require.config({
paths: {
jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
templates: '../templates',
Handlebars: 'libs/handlebars/Handlebars',
codebird:'libs/codebird-js-develop/codebird',
oauth:'libs/oauth',
**spin:'libs/spin'**

}

});

require([

'app',

], function(App){


 App.initialize();
});
```

and called this library in a view,but console tells me that `Spinner`(function in library) is not defined:

```
define(["spin"],
function (spin) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

After defining the paths try add a shim config like:-

```
shim: {
spin: {
  deps: ['jquery'],
  exports: 'spin'
}
}
```

I don't know whether spin.js requires jquery or not, it's just an example, but spin.js requires any other libray try to define that in dependency otherwise just define the exports.

Also check whether you're using the amd version of spin.js or not.

Comment: `shim` is only needed for libraries that aren't AMD-compatible, and [Spin.js, well, is...](https://github.com/fgnass/spin.js/blob/2.0.1/spin.js#L10)

Comment: @indra answer is correct to me. if you dont want to use shiw, then convert it to UMD or AMD